# PBS code for submitting a job on the cluster

Tags: ssh, cluster, high-performance

I'm trying to write a code to submit a job on the cluster, and am using someone else's previous code as a template; is there any way someone could explain each line step by step to me? I think I understand the nodes and wall time since I've looked at some tutorials but I'm having trouble understanding the last 3 lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=12
#PBS -l walltime=96:00:00
#PBS -q python
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
perl cal_gerp_crmcre.pl GERP++ CRM_NCR.data  >CRECRM_NCR.gp
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a shell that is your script using.

The lines starting with `#PBS` are passed to the [`qsub`](http://www2.astro.psu.edu/nr/computers/manifold/man/pbs/qsub.1.html) command. The first two (`-l`) specify the resource limits and the `-q` specifies the destination of the job (the name of a queue, a server, or a queue at a server). This looks like a queue named `python`.

The last two lines are the script itself. One is changing working directory to the current working directory of the `qsub` command (from where you submit the job?). The last is running the perl script `cal_gerp_crmcre.pl`, storing its output to `CRECRM_NCR.gp`.

I hope it makes sense for an overview. All the information I used is available in the manual page for [`qsub`](http://www2.astro.psu.edu/nr/computers/manifold/man/pbs/qsub.1.html), where you can find also more examples and options.